# callback within a function which should return to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Working in node.js and trying to get node to run python-shell, calculate a value and then return the answer to computePython() as an object with key result.

How do I get message to return to result: FutureValue() ?
console.log(message) works within .on('message'..

```
function computePython(){
  return {
  result: FutureValue() // I want message from FutureValue() to show up here
  };
}

function FutureValue(){
  var rate = 0.05;
  var nper = 10;
  var pmt = 100;
  var pv = 100;
  var result;

  new PythonShell('future_value.py', jsc(options, {
    args: [rate, nper, pmt, pv]
    }))
    .on('message', function (message) {
       console.log(message); //works
       return message;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think you should use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because this processing is asynchronous, you can use `Promise` to make your code more clear and reusable :

```
function computePython(){
  getFutureValue().then(function(value) {
      // do what you want with value here
  });
}

function getFutureValue(){
  var rate = 0.05;
  var nper = 10;
  var pmt = 100;
  var pv = 100;
  var result;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    new PythonShell('future_value.py', jsc(options, {
        args: [rate, nper, pmt, pv]
    }))
      .on('message', resolve);
  })
}
```

Comment: still struggling, console.log(value) works, but the return value ends up with {"result"; {}}   any ideas?                                                                                                 function computePython(){
  return {
    result: FutureValue().then(function(value) {
      console.log(value); //works
      return value; //returns empty
  })
  };
}

Comment: You want to say that you receive the message from PythonShell execution but it is empty => `{result: {}}` ?

Comment: Yes, so I did like you said and get the message from PythonShell to computerPython. When I run computePython with console.log(value) and return value in the //do what you want with value here, the console.log shows the value, but the return value returns undefined.

Comment: Could it be because I emit it before its done calculating? Perhaps I need to create another promise: io.emit('runPython', computePython());